# Silver version badge of vox populi?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting-badges

How about adding a silver version of vox populi badge?

That should encourage people to vote more.

Comment: If you're not even going to suggest what it does or what the criteria for awarding it will be...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn No, I will not suggest. I just wanted to see if it is a stupid idea, and apparently it is (according to votes). Or, did I ask in a bad way?

Comment: Well, as you have seen, Lucifer came up with a completely random suggestion, to which you replied that you never said it should have that criteria. So what do *you* have in mind for the badge?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Obviously, you get a badge after using 40 votes for N days. The question is not the number, but whether such badge should exist.

Comment: Encouraging voting is perhaps something we could do better. However, what criteria should be the gate keeper for earning this badge? Silver badges should be a bit hard to earn. Perhaps consider what might _disqualify_ someone from earning the badge, based on the feedback you received? :) Perhaps the system never invalidating votes from that user? That would mean you are voting well, and helping, and I don't disagree on the idea of an intermediate badge for those managing to accomplish just that.

Answer (score 3):

I do not find it useful. Vox Populi is for one time badge. Making it silver version = Used 40 votes for 100 days, which may cause **random or otherwise mindless voting** just to earn the badge.

> **Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested.** (from [SO badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges), written under "Legend" caption)

Neither making it silver increases knowledge.

Comment: I nowhere said it should be 40 votes for 100 days

Comment: See the basic rule for silver

Comment: Where to see those rules?

Comment: well better you first check it, and the suggest for it

Comment: I still don't get it. What should I check? Where are the basic rules for silver? Which suggest are you talking about?

Comment: you have silver badge of discussion, just put mouse pointer and read the tool tip

Comment: *A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.* I still don't see how it matters for silver badges.

Comment: @VJovic "Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested." - that's what I read at [SO badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/badges), under "Legend" caption

Comment: So, Lucifer, are you saying that vox populi badge causes lots of false voting, and should be removed? @gnat Thanks, I haven't seen that so far.

Comment: yes, a kind of that, and My meaning was also just as what gnat said.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this suggestion, but your "reasoning" for disliking it doesn't make sense. It's borderline offensive to put words in the OP's mouth the way you did... at _best_, it's somewhat duplicitous.

Comment: I don't think he meant 'false' as in sockery, I think @Lucifer meant false as in 'Let me go find some stuff to vote for, quickly .. so I get this badge' and that is a valid concern.

Comment: @BЈовић Testing the `@reply` feature, in response to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133385/stopped-receiving-messages-to-inbox-after-rename). Do you receive a notification of this comment?

Comment: Since he hasn't replied you back in 16 mins, let me tell you that i received the notification as long as you put it. @TheEstablishment